# Why ubuntu installer is not showing the unallocated space while dual booting with windows 11

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Well, I am using an asus laptop with 512GB SSD. I turned off the bitlocker encryption and made an unallocated space of 120GB also turned off the secure boot option in BIOS. But while installing it does not show any Install alongside with windows option I tried the other option also but it does not my 120GB free space .

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop LTS latest version

Comment: Re-read the instructions. There are additional steps.